# Why is my WNIC MAC changing every reboot?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, mac-address

The university I attend scans student and faculty machines with an agent (Bradford) to ensure they comply with policy (i.e. AV is installed and up-to date, and the OS is patched). The system's MAC address is then tied to a user's domain account. Sometime last week, the campus network started claiming that my laptop was unregistered after a reboot.

I contacted a network admin, who discovered that five different MAC addresses had been associated with my laptop's WNIC. Upon further investigation, I discovered that somehow, the last two hex digits of the WNIC MAC that is reported to Windows 7 has started to change after a reboot of the system. I don't use any spoofing software.

Could this be caused by faulty hardware? The MAC prefix (00E04C) does correspond the correct OEM (Realtek). The WNIC is a RTL8723AE. My next step is to see if the same thing occurs when booted to a Linux distro.

Comment: While related to a security function of your university, this sounds more like a system troubleshooting question. It is probably more appropriate for [su]. If you would like it moved, please flag it for the moderators to migrate - do not cross-post.

Comment: I would just pick one and configure the interface to use that one from now on.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I'm still curious about this. I've never seen anything like what OP reports. Any sane explanation?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Unfortunately, the Windows drivers do not offer that setting, and Linux support is practically nonexistent. I'd rather not use a workaround anyway. I've ordered an Intel 6235AN as a replacement, which I should have tomorrow.

Comment: @vonbrand My first thought was this might be a symptom of some malware (for [ARP Spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing) or something). After I got my paranoia in check, I decided that the most likely explanation a failure in the WNIC hardware. I'll post an update once I've replaced it.

Comment: FYI the RTL8723AE is supported by Linux starting with the 3.8 kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the WNIC, and all is well.